# What are the advantages of using SiriKali vs something like Veracrypt?

Tags: encryption

So what are the advantages of using SiriKali vs. something like Veracrypt.  They both essentially do the same thing correct.  I assume Veracrypt would be more secure.  What are the differences between the two.  I know they use different encryption methods, but wouldn't you just always want to use the one that is more secure. Encryption times? I'm guessing that SiriKali is just a GUI to manage different types of encrypted files?

Comment: *"I'm guessing that SiriKali is just a GUI to manage different types of encrypted files?"* - no need to guess here. That's actually clear from the very first sentence on the [SiriKali homepage](https://mhogomchungu.github.io/sirikali/): *SiriKali is a Qt/C++ GUI application that manages ecryptfs, cryfs, encfs, gocryptfs, fscrypt and securefs based encrypted folders. "*.

Answer (score 1):

SiriKali is a **front-end** for various **folder based** encryption implementations while Veracrypt is an actual **implementation** of **full disk** encryption.

So you are trying to compare here encryption front-end vs. encryption implementation - which makes no sense. If you just look at the encryption you are comparing various implementations vs. a single implementation, which isn't that practical either.

On a conceptual level you compare file based encryption vs. full disk encryption. There are already many similar questions here, so there is no need to repeat it here. See instead:

- [Full disk encryption vs home folder encryption - why should the former be chosen over the latter](/questions/185027)
- [Does File-Based Encryption offer comparable security to Full-Disk Encryption on Android?](/questions/216655)
- [Disk Encryption vs File Encryption for Embedded Linux?](/questions/162904/)
- [Which is more secure a full disk or file encryption?](/questions/109351)

See also [Wikipedia:Disk encryption
| Disk encryption vs. filesystem-level encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption#Disk_encryption_vs._filesystem-level_encryption) about this topic.